# adding clients fails on identityserver4 on missing property

Tags: identityserver4

I'm following the documentation from https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstarts/5_entityframework.html

I used the SQL scripts instead of migrations as was linked in the article from here: https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/tree/master/src/EntityFramework.Storage/migrations/SqlServer/Migrations

When trying the step Initializing the Database it does not work cause the Clients Table has more columns than is in the class IdentityServer4.Model.Client.

The property RequireRequestObject is missing from the Class for example... Is the linked SQL Script not updated or wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out myself. Had to go back to an earlier version which fits with the current identityserver4 version:

https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/tree/41f83cd7bf22c87fd4be98df9b8eaefafd80dbc2/src/EntityFramework.Storage/migrations/SqlServer/Migrations